# If $f(x)=\sin^2(3-x)$, then what is $f'(0)?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been doing the math myself and my answer happened to be $-\sin(6)$, am I just being really stupid here and unable to convert it to any of the answers or my answer is wrong (or the answers are wrong)?

> (a) $–2\cos(3)$
>
> (b) $–2\sin(3)\cos(3)$
>
> (c) $6\cos(3)$
>
> (d) $2\sin(3)\cos(3)$
>
> (e) $6\sin(3)\cos(3)$

Comment: Your answer is the same as option B, as $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: $\sin(2x)=2\cos(x)\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0):

If $$f(x)=\sin^{2}(3-x)$$  then by chain rule, we have

$$f'(x)=2\sin(3-x)\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(3-x))$$

$$f'(x)=2\sin(3-x)\cos(3-x)(-1)$$ 
$$=-2\sin (3-x) \cos(3-x)$$

Now, $ \sin (2x)=2\sin (x)\cos (x)$ ( identity)

, so $$-\sin (6-2x)=-2\sin (3-x)\cos (3-x)$$

$$f'(0)=-2\sin (3)\cos (3)$$

or if you prefer, $f'(0)=2\sin (-3)\cos (-3)$

Comment: This is incorrect